# Get data with spesific by month with sequelize

Tags: mysql, express, orm, sequelize.js

I have a problem with sequelize use MySql, I've already googling and I got nothing.

MyData
name : DataTypes.STRING,
date: DataTypes.DATE

How can I get all data from table MyData, with specific month using date's column?

I want all MyData from month = inputFromUser.
I try this, but I didnt get it
[Get current month with Sequel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187609/get-current-month-with-sequel)

Thank you guys.